# signalr Clients.Users(userIds).send(msg) not firing

Tags: c#, signalr

I have single R version 2.2.1.
I implement custom Id Provider

```
public class ChatUserIdProvider : IUserIdProvider
{
    public string GetUserId(IRequest request)
    {
        if (request.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            Guid.Parse(request.User.Identity.GetUserId().ToString());
            var userId = request.User.Identity.GetUserId().ToString();
            return userId.ToString();
        }
        return "Un Known";
    }
}
```

I made a simple chat app and every think OK, but when I try to send a message to multi users the client event not firing 
here is hub function

```
public void SendToMany(string msg, List<string> userIds)
    {
        try
        {
           //db things here
            Clients.Users(userIds).sendMessage(msg);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logs.Log(ex);
        }
    }
```

Startup

```
  GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(IUserIdProvider), () => new ChatUserIdProvider ());
        app.MapSignalR();
```

Js

```
$(function () {
   var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
    chat.client.sendMessage= function (msg) {
        $('.msgs').append('<div>'+ group.Name + '</div>');
        $('#' + group.Id).click();
    }
   $.connection.hub.start();

})

function BrodCast() {
    try {

        var chatids = new Array();
        $('.ckusergr').each(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                chatids.push($(this).attr('iid'));
            }
        })
        chat.server.sendToMany($('.txtmsg').val(), chatids);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}
```

the problem with this line

```
public void SendToMany(string msg, List<string> userIds)
    {
        try
        {
           //db things here
            Clients.Users(userIds).sendMessage(msg); // Her is the Problem
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logs.Log(ex);
        }
    }
```

if I change to become like this every thing work great.

```
public void SendToMany(string msg, List<string> userIds)
    {
        try
        {
            //db things here
            foreach (string item in userIds)
            {
                Clients.User(item).sendMessage(msg);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logs.Log(ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Clients.User` works with User ID which is string. it does not work with list of string. so you need to use foreach for it to work. im not sure how you design it, but you could consider using `Clients.All`. it would automatically send the message to All online clients

Comment: you are wright `Clients.User` work with string `user Id`, but I am trying with `Clients.Users` which is accept list of user ids

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem today and I find out when I send as parameter `List<string>` which contains all usernames into `Clients.Users(list of usernames)` somehow it will work also.

I found this by accident, maybe someone with better experiences may clarify why this is working since this should only accept `IList<string> userIds`

Comment: `IList<string>` is interface while `List<string>` is class Inherit from IList so the parameter will accept all the class which is Inherited from `IList<string>`

Comment: Thanks for explanation

Answer (score 1):

- First, you need to start your `hub` before declaring 'send' function.
- Second, you should put your `Broadcast function` inside the main function which is declaring variable chat.

something like this should work :

```
$(function () {
   var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
    chat.client.sendMessage= function (msg) {
        $('.msgs').append('<div>'+ group.Name + '</div>');
        $('#' + group.Id).click();
    }
   $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        var chatids = new Array();
        $('.ckusergr').each(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                chatids.push($(this).attr('iid'));
            }
        })
        chat.server.sendToMany($('.txtmsg').val(), chatids);
    });
})
```

Comment: I already start the hub, but I forgot to sent in the question.
I tried also to set the Broadcast function inside the main function but the same, the sendMessage function is not firing. I Edit the question to be more clear