# SignalR send notifications to users by userId

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I got Notification hub where I got method supposed to send some sort of message to involved users by their Id using `Clients.Users()` method which accept as parameter `IList<string> UserIds`.

In Notification class I got some sort of message and in second List parameter i got only users Id which i take from my database.

```
public void NewProjectNotification(Notification notification, List<string> involvedUsers)
{
    IHubContext _ctx = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationHub>();
    _ctx.Clients.Users(involvedUsers).newProjectNotification(notification);
}
```

My problem is that when this hub method is fired it never reach my angularJS client method to broadcast this notification

```
$scope.notifications = NotificationService.newProjectNotification(function(callback){
    $scope.OverAllCount = $scope.OverAllCount + 1;
    $scope.notification.push(callback.Value);
});
```

My problem is clearly with `Clients.Users()` method since when i use `All` method for broadcasting this message to all connected users, it works fine, but I want only to send it to involved users, not to all.

I know there is also `Clients()` method which accepts `List<string> connectionIds` but I would like to know I do wrong in this case.

**EDIT :**

1) _ctx is Hub context which I use for accessing clients method

2) about Id's... I got project form where I pass involved users, after that I extract their Id's and store them into `List` and just send it as parameter to my Hub method

Comment: How to you create the list with your user ids? And what is _ctx. How do you get this context?

Comment: Hi, I updated my question

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42109363/signalr-clients-usersuserids-sendmsg-not-firing
I belief this is the same question

Comment: Thanks for this post, didnt find it before. Anyway I discovered that when I send `List` of usernames into `Clients.Users()` method, it works perfectly which I found a quite odd and I found it by accident.